# Правильно ли сверстана форма?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
 button {
    display:block;
    border:3px solid #d5d6d7;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:white;
    background:#5ca0ca;
    padding:12px 80px;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:15px;
    margin-top:54px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:114px;
  }

  input {
    padding:5px;
  }

  .form-input {
    margin-left:20px;
    width:202px;
  }
```

```html
<form action="" class="form">
    <input style="display:block;border:2px solid #316e94;border-radius:5px;width:339px;" 
    type="text" placeholder="Example: Wichita Falls, Texas 76301">
    <input style="margin-bottom:15px;margin-top:8px;" type="checkbox" id="qwerty">
    <label for="qwerty">Include surrounding suburbs</label><br>
    <label for="qwerty1">Property type:</label>
    <input style="margin-bottom:20px;" class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Select one">            
    <br>
    <label style="margin-left:17px;" for="qwerty2">Bedrooms :</label>
    <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Select one">
    <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

Я явно где-то напортачил, потому что были использованы 
. Я не могу сверстать часть ( будет обведена красным на картинке) без 
. Помогите. Предложите ваш вариант.
Также хотелось бы спросить, я правильно понимаю, что тег  по-умолчанию имеет строчный тип( то есть он строчный элемент)?
Извините за такой вопрос, но мне просто не у кого спросить.

[image: Картинка с формой]

Comment: Так у вас все так и сверстано, не понимаю вопроса

Comment: @RuslanSemenov я вот не могу сверстать ( эту часть красной области нормально, без <br>). Я прямо чувствую, что здесь я сверстал, да, но криво. Я хочу без костылей это делать. Можете предложить свой вариант этой верстки?

Comment: ну да они объединяются в блоки `<div>`

Comment: @RuslanSemenov можете показать на примере? Мне, как новичку, тяжело понять.

Answer (score 3):

Тут полет мысли, вариантов миллион, к примеру так:

```css
body {
  background-color: #4c91bb;
  color: white;
}

button {
  border: 3px solid #d5d6d7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  background: #5ca0ca;
  padding: 0.5rem 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center
}

input {
  padding: 5px;
}

form>div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

d .form-input {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 202px;
}

.field>label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block
}

.address {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #316e94;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 339px;
}

checkbox {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="form">
  <div>
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input id="address" class="address" type="text" placeholder="Example: Wichita Falls, Texas 76301">
    <input type="checkbox" id="qwerty">
    <label for="qwerty">Include surrounding suburbs</label>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="qwerty1">Property type:</label>
    <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Select one">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="qwerty2">Bedrooms :</label>
    <input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Select one">
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button>Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
button {
 display:block;
 border:3px solid #d5d6d7;
 border-radius:5px;
 color:white;
 background:#5ca0ca;
 padding:12px 80px;
 cursor:pointer;
 font-size:15px;
 margin-top:34px;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin-left:124px;
}
input {
 padding:5px;
}

.form-input {
 margin:0 0 20px 20px;
 width:202px;
}
.text-input{
  display:block;
  border:2px solid #316e94;
  border-radius:5px;
  width:339px;   
}
.check-input{
  margin-bottom:15px;
  margin-top:8px;
}
form div p{
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  min-width:100px;
  text-align:end;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="form">
    <p>Adderss, Suburbs, Postcodes, or Regions</p>
    <input class="text-input"type="text" placeholder="Example: Wichita Falls, Texas 76301">   
    <div><input class="check-input" type="checkbox"><p>Include surrounding suburbs</p></div>
    <div><p>Property type:</p><input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Select one"> </div>
    <div><p>Bedrooms :</p><input class="form-input" type="text" placeholder="Select one"></div>           
    <button>Search</button>
</form>
```

Форма сверстана не правильно, старайтесь избегать прямого назначения стилей(style="") используйте классы или id. Да input изначально строчный элемент.
Код формы отправлю позже.

Comment: Отправьте, пожалуйста, свой вариант. Мне, как начинающему, очень интересно посмотреть ваше видение на форму.

Comment: По сути можно сделать лучше, повозиться с классами и тд, чисто для визуального оргазма, но это я оставляю на вас